# Finding coordinate representations of bases containing polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I have an even-numbered homework problem whose answer is not in the book and am seeking clarification as to how to obtain the answers.

Part A: for $P(t) = 2t^2 - 4$, find its coordinate representation with respect to the standard basis $E$. In other words, find $[P(t)]_E$. If my calculations are correct, the column vector for this should be $[-4, 0, 2]'$. Standard basis $E = \{1, t, t^2\}$ and other basis $B = \{1 + t + t^2, 1+t, 1\}$

Part B: This is where I'm tripping up. I am required to find a change of coordinates matrix $P _{E\leftarrow B} = M^{B E}$. To do this, would I just need to find $[P(t)]_B$ and then use those two column vectors as my matrix for the change of coordinates matrix?

Part C: This part asks me to do what I assumed I need to do in part B, which is find $[P(t)]$ with respect to $B$ this time instead of $E$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: This question would be much better if formatted using MathJax. Also, what is the basis B that you refer to here? It doesn't seem to be mentioned

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Forgot to input those. I've added them to the problem.

Comment: This is a standard change of basis problem - you need to express the basis elements of the standard basis in terms of the new basis - this will give you the entries of the transformation matrix - then you apply that to your original point it will give it to you in changed form

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I need a matrix for this. How do I derive a matrix from polynomials?